# Python replace word after a match in a file

Tags: python, replace

We are looking for replacing a word after each match in a list of words for each line in a file

> This is Manager Sam speaking.Hello, how are you? I am Fine. this is
>   Director Tom. Nice to Meet you Manager Sam.

```
import re
f1=open('testinput.txt', 'r')
f2=open('testoutput.txt', 'w')
checkWords = ["Manager","Director"]
repWords = ("*** ")

for line in f1:
    i = 0
    for i in range(len(checkWords)):
        # Find the next word after the search word
        list1 = re.compile(r'%s\s+((?:\w+(?:\s+!$)) {1})' %checkWords[i]).findall(line)
        checkWords = ','.join(list1)
        print(checkWords)
        line = line.replace(checkWords, repWords)
        print(line)
        f2.write(line)
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

Expected Output:

```
This is Manager *** speaking.Hello, how are you?
I am Fine. this is Director *** Nice to Meet you Manager ***
```

But, Output I am getting now:

```
*** T*** h*** i*** s***  *** i*** s***  *** M*** a*** n*** a*** g*** e*** r***  *** S*** a*** m***  *** s*** p*** e*** a*** k*** i*** n*** g*** .*** H*** e*** l*** l*** o*** ,***  *** h*** o*** w***  *** a*** r*** e***  *** y*** o*** u*** ?***
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible way to do this:

```
pre_words = ['Manager', 'Director']
with open('testoutput.txt', 'w') as f0:
    with open('testinput.txt') as f1:
        for line in f1.readlines():
            l = line.split()
            j = ['***' if i>0 and l[i-1] in pre_words else l[i] for i in range(len(l))]
            f0.write(' '.join(j)+'\n')
```

Output:

```
This is Manager *** speaking.Hello, how are you?
I am Fine. this is Director *** Nice to Meet you Manager ***
```

Comment: Works Great.. Any Idea why the below Text input fails:   

This is Manager Sam speaking.Hello, how are you? Manager kim
I am Fine. this is Director Tom. Nice to Meet you Manager Sam.Director Tim

Comment: It fails because in the second line, it is interpreting "Sam.Director" as a single word instead of two separate ones.

Answer (score 0):

```
lines=open('testinput.txt', 'r').read().split('\n')

checkWords = ["Manager","Director"]
repWords = "***"

out = []
flag = False

for line in lines:
    line_out = []
    for word in line.split(' '):
        if flag:
            line_out.append(repWords)
            flag = False
        else:
            line_out.append(word)
        if word in checkWords:
            flag=True
    out.append(' '.join(line_out))
with open('testoutput.txt', 'w') as f2:
    f2.write('\n'.join(out))
```

Is this what you need?

Comment: Fair enough. Any Idea why the below Text input fails:   

This is Manager Sam speaking.Hello, how are you? Manager kim
I am Fine. this is Director Tom. Nice to Meet you Manager Sam.Director Tim

Comment: Because that code is looking for words seperated by space, and there is no space before 'Director Tim'. Just add a space. That's not only parsable, but also correct unlike what you did.